# JetBrains IDE inspection of Character sequence ']]>' must not appear in content unless used to mark the end of a CDATA section

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-inspection

##### The problem

There is a highlighting (warning) displayed in the code in the various IDE's of JetBrains, in my case WebStorm and PhpStorm, that suggests that by concatenating strings the IDE does not recognize that it is the end of a CDATA section.

[image: WebStorm 2022.1.2]

> `Character sequence ']]>' must not appear in content unless used to mark the end of a CDATA section`

The assumption that this inspection can be configured in the settings of the IDE, I can not confirm after research on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=%22must%20not%20appear%22) or SO. Due to the integrated language injection it is also not clear whether the IDE reports the problem due to inspection rules of the `HTML` or `XML` syntax (injection).

Tests have shown that when you disable all injection rules related to `HTML` and `XML`, the warning continues to be issued. These messages appear for concatenated stings in `.js`, `.ts` and `.php` files. Also in `.html` & `.xml` files (without injection) the warnings are highlighted.

There seem to be a few older tickets. However, these are not resolved and do not provide a solution.

##### The question

Does anyone have experience with this problem in specifically these IDE's or a solution to a Language Injection pattern? I don't suspect the latter, because the warnings are also thrown in files that don't have a language injection (`.html` & `.xml` etc.).

Comment: This has to be that it is a HTML injection. If you force XML there instead then it should not be shown, e.g.  https://i.imgur.com/kzJ9MdC.png It's a bit hard to see with my color scheme (current line has yellow background; the same as a Warning background) , but I wanted to show that it is indeed a XML there (the intentions/quick fix menu content). Here I have force-injected XML via a comment (and therefore override the auto-injected HTML). You can manually write it or use the intentions/quick fix menu to insert it (the actual language you will have to adjust manually).

Comment: *"Also in `.html` & `.xml` files (without injection) the warnings are highlighted."* Can you provide a minimal file content to play with? I do not see such complaints in my XML files.

Comment: For reference purposes: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56255

Comment: @LazyOne [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56255](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56255)  is already marked as duplicate. In the meantime I have the problem only with the language injection and no longer with the plain files. I will test your first advice. Thanks a lot!